# batch script - How to conditionally redirect output stream(s)

Tags: batch, batch-file, redirection, stdout, stderr

In summary, the goal is twofold:

- Create a logfile that only contains commands that have failed, plus the error messages those commands generate.
- Prevent console output (success or failure), except for messages I want echo'ed.

I'm trying to work out how to basically do something like this in a batch file:

`@CmdThatWillFail || Redirect original command + error message to a file` 

I'm trying to capture the originating command its accompanying error message -- but only if there is an error, whilst suppressing all output to the console.  I realize I can't use @ in front of every command nor have ECHO turned off in order to capture the originating command, so I'm not even sure if this is possible.

I'm not aware of any way to expand or reference the previously run command other than using Doskey.  I've tried using `doskey /history` in tandem with `more` and other ways of retreiving the last command, but haven't come up with a working solution yet.  I've also fiddled around with alternate data streams but I don't feel like that's a sound solution.  Lastly, I've tried several combinations of things like the following:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO %DATE% %TIME:~0,-3% > Log.txt
CALL :Function >>Log.txt 2>&1
ECHO Script finished.  Press any key to exit. . . && PAUSE >NUL
EXIT /B

:Function
@ECHO ON
DIR FileThatDoesNotExist >NUL
DIR Log.txt >NUL
@ECHO This will show up in the log, but not the console.
@ECHO This will show up in the console, but not the log. >CON:
@ECHO How can this be redirected to show up in both log and console?
@ECHO OFF
```

### Console output:

```
This will show up in the console, but not the log.
How can this be redirected to show up in both log and console?
Script finished.  Press any key to exit. . .
```

- Using `>CON` (thank you [Destroy666](https://superuser.com/users/1145698/destroy666)) within `:Function` works perfectly to echo to console and prevent echoing to log.

### Log output:

```
Thu 05/11/2023  12:00:00

C:\Scripts>DIR FileThatDoesNotExist  1>NUL 
File Not Found

C:\Scripts>DIR Log.txt  1>NUL   <----- How to suppress commands that succeed?

This will show up in the log, but not the console.
```

- The failed command `DIR FileThatDoesNotExist >NUL` was logged along with the error message it generated `File Not Found`, and both were suppressed from the console.  This is exactly what I'm looking for.

### Still left to iron out:

- `C:\Scripts>DIR Log.txt  1>NUL` completed successfully but still shows up in the log - I would like to suppress successful commands (and their output) from the console *and* the log.  How can this be achieved?
- How can something be echoed to both the console and the log?

I'm trying to keep this relatively simple and clean(ish) and not introduce powershell calls, using Tee-Object, 3rd party tools, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** based on edit.

What you want doesn't look to be possible without using external tools or at least not reasonably achievable.

The only possible operations involving `>` and streams in CMD that I know of are:

- `2>&1`, `2>&3`, `3>&9` - redirecting between numbered streams, where `1` and `2` are `stdout` and `stedrr` and further ones up to `9` are not reserved
- `1>NUL` - redirecting to void
- `2>CON` - redirecting to console output

E.g. copying or reusing streams, which would solve one of your 2 remaining problems, is not quite doable without external tools, like mentioned tee. Installing that is much more recommended than trying weird workarounds that will make your code look horrendous in the end.

Also, if you used PowerShell instead, you'd have [Tee-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-7.3) available by default.

Comment: Changing that one line actually echoed each command to the console and redirected the error message(s) to the log.  I updated my question with a better explanation along with output examples that I'm looking to achieve.  Using >CON is helpful though - thank you!  Using >CON  within :Function helps to control where output is being redirected (console or log).  The two things left to nail down have been included in my updated question.

Comment: I really don't think you should try this kind of things within a very outdated technology such as batch, which I wouldn't even recommend using in the 1st place, without help of an external tools on top. I edited with my recommendation to either install tee or use PowerShell instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for more finite control of what is going on, you can use the following sort of method.  @Destroy666 method is probably what you need but this is another way to approach the problem.  You also might want to redirect output in the for /f function in whatever way you need.

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO %DATE% %TIME:~0,-3% > Log.txt
for /f "delims=" %%l ('command_here') do call :EvalFunction "%%l" "%ERRORLEVEL%" 
ECHO Script finished.  Press any key to exit. . . && PAUSE  >NUL
goto :EOF

:EvalFunction
Set TextError=%~1
Set IntError=%~2
if [%IntError%]==[0] goto :EOF
echo %TextError% >Log.txt
goto :EOF
```

'''

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) I'm trying to find a method that can be applied to several commands in a batch script, not just one single command, so this might not be practical for larger scripts (which I'm working with).